# How to get overlay of building footprint using geojson

Tags: python, mapbox, geojson

I've got this method returning an image for use by a real time semantic segmentation endpoint.  I'd
like to try the geojson route instead of relying on imagery/deep learning to get the building footprint, and related surface area.

Given latitude and longitude, use overpass API to get the building footprint geojson nodes, then pass those to overlay an image on top of the roof.

I'm interested in getting the surface area as well, but I think I can write that once I have the image processing working.

I currently use a DL model I trained to perform semantic segmentation on the image, but it's not reliable as satellite images often have trees or poor lighting.

Here's what I have to get the image (which works fine):

```
lat, lng = get_lat_lng()
base_url = "https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/satellite-v9/static"coordinates = f"{lng},{lat},{19},1"size="512x512"access_token=os.environ.get('MAPBOX_API')

params = {"access_token": access_token}

image_url = f"{base_url}/{coordinates}/{size}"
response = requests.get(image_url, params=params)
image = open_image(response)
return image
```

Does anyone have experience with the overpy to take the lat, lng and get the building coordinates? Ideally I would pass that as a param here and see the image I want.

I tried something like this in a separate file from the application, but it was not gathering the right geojson coordinates, and not drawing anything:

```
import requests
import overpy
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
from io import BytesIO
from shapely.geometry import shape, Polygon

api = overpy.Overpass()
query = f'node(around:lat, lng);out;'
result = api.query(query)

building_coordinates = []
for node in result.nodes:
    building_coordinates.append((node.lon, node.lat))

building_polygon = Polygon(building_coordinates)
geojson_data = building_polygon.__geo_interface__
image_url = "https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/satellite-v9/static/-77.3385,39.0342,18.08,0/512x512?before_layer=building&access_token=TOKEN"
response = requests.get(image_url)
map_image = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(map_image)
boundary = building_polygon.exterior.coords
scaled_boundary = [
    (int((lon + 180) * (map_image.width / 360)), int((90 - lat) * (map_image.height / 180)))
    for lon, lat in boundary
]
draw.polygon(scaled_boundary, outline="red")

map_image.save("overlay_image.png")
```